# Take a PHP function to Mysql that uses decimal numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to take this function from php to mysql:

```
    function distancia($p1LA, $p1LO, $p2LA, $p2LO) {
    $r = 6371.0;

    $p1LA = $p1LA * pi() / 180.0;
    $p1LO = $p1LO * pi() / 180.0;
    $p2LA = $p2LA * pi() / 180.0;
    $p2LO = $p2LO * pi() / 180.0;

    $dLat = $p2LA - $p1LA;
    $dLong = $p2LO - $p1LO;

    $a = sin($dLat / 2) * sin($dLat / 2) + cos($p1LA) * cos($p2LA) * sin($dLong / 2) * sin($dLong / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));

    return round($r * $c * 1000); 
}
```

And on mysql, I'm doing this:

```
DELIMITER |
 CREATE FUNCTION Distancia (la1 DECIMAL, lo1 DECIMAL, la2 DECIMAL, lo2 DECIMAL)
  RETURNS DECIMAL
   DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
     DECLARE r DECIMAL;

     DECLARE la1aux DECIMAL;
     DECLARE lo1aux DECIMAL;
     DECLARE la2aux DECIMAL;
     DECLARE lo2aux DECIMAL;
     DECLARE retorno DECIMAL;

     DECLARE dLat DECIMAL;
     DECLARE dLong DECIMAL;

     DECLARE a DECIMAL;
     DECLARE c DECIMAL;

     SET r = 6371.0;     

     SET la1aux = la1 * pi()/180.0;     
     SET lo1aux = lo1 * pi()/180.0;     
     SET la2aux = la2 * pi()/180.0;     
     SET lo2aux = lo2 * pi()/180.0;     

     SET dLat = la2aux - la1aux;
     SET dLong = lo2aux - lo1aux;

     SET a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) + cos(la1aux) * cos(la2aux) * sin(dLong / 2) * sin(dLong / 2);
     SET c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

     SET retorno = round(r * c * 1000);

     RETURN retorno;
    END|
```

Im calling the function on mysql like this:

```
select Distancia(-46.61579100, -23.54247250, -46.61354560, -23.54093070)/1000;
```

The result should be 0.276. But Im getting 0. I never worked with a procedure or function on mysql before, so I dont know what  I could be missing. I tried to make the decimal variables decimal(11,8), and it didnt work too. 
Anyone with a little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do calculations with floating numbers where calculations are not simple ones (adding, multiplication) and when the subtotals exceed the bounds of the datatype (especially when you use decimal without scale and precision), you better use float-datatype. You can at the end choose how many decimals you want the result to be.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed every decimal on my mysql function and its working properly now.